# What is life like for a clone trooper or a stormtrooper?

Tags: star-wars, clones, stormtroopers

I know *The Clone Wars* (the current CGI animated series, not the original animated one) shows what training is like for the clones and we see the clones and some of what they go through while serving along side the Jedi.

But what is life, overall, like for clone troopers?  Do they get leave and are they allowed R&R, or, as clones, are they expected to have no concern in life but to fight and die?

And how about stormtroopers that aren't clones?  In *Episode IV*, when Obi-Wan is sneaking by a couple stormtroopers, we hear them talking about something that may be a weapon or a vehicle (I don't remember the exact line), so they do tend to have an interest either in their equipment or in other things in life.

Are both troopers expected to give up everything for their life as a soldier, or, on average, is there more to them and their lives, than being ready and doing well in battle?

Comment: Well, the conversation sucks. *"Nice gun." "Thanks, yours is the same." "Oh yeah. Um, nice suit." "Same as yours." "OK, um..." "Look, we've got the same brain, I know what you're going to say." "Yeah, you're right. By the way, nice hair." "Oh, shut up."*

Comment: Days or weeks of tedium punctuated by moments of sheer adrenaline and violence.  Much the same as any military during times of unrest.

Comment: These videos should sum it up!  ;)  http://www.trooperclerks.com/films_cartoons.html

Comment: There was a [clone bar](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/79%27s/Canon) on Coruscant.  It was also frequented by females, so clearly the clones were doing something in their free time!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They do not have a home during the empire. They are billeted on a ship, barracks, or they sleep where they can in the field.  They are soldiers but they are defacto slaves as they can not choose not to serve and they are engineered to die young.

Post empire they find a home on Mandolore and many of the old units act as mercenaries.  There are several books "The Republic Commando Series" that address their culture and several other appearances in novels including one that dealt with finding a cure for the Death Gene.

Comment: Is this just clone troopers, or does it apply to storm troopers as well?

Comment: As far as where they live yes.  There are some former stormtroopers that were conscripted post destruction of the clone world that pop up in some of the stories.  It seems most of them either continued life in the Military under the New Republic/GA or became civilians.  Since they were not subjected to the same process of creation/training/deathgene the regular stormtroopers would have been more able to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the actual clones are allowed to, like, retire or have leave, but the non-clone stormtroopers are allowed leave based on some novels I've read. And they do have recreation, because in Clone Wars Gambit: Siege the clones are playing darts and roughhousing, but since the EU isn't canon anymore it depends how valid you consider the EU as a source.

Comment: Until Disney releases enough material to replace, or at the very least, compensate for the loss of EU, I consider it valid.