# Stormtrooper sanitation

Tags: star-wars, stormtroopers

Stormtrooper Armor was good in its time, and did a good job of protecting the individual stormtrooper.  However, even Clones have to eat as shown in some of the examples, such as scenes at Kaminos showing them eating.  So how did Stormtroopers prevent having to eliminate urine and fecal waste, at the wrong time?  Did they have a enhanced digestive and urinary system that allowed a very small amount of urine and feces to be expelled at a longer time than humans?

Comment: I always thought that was a toilet paper dispenser on their lower back

Comment: Is there any good reason to assume that they didn't just take off their lower coverings and wee behind a nearby tree/dune?

Comment: Do members of the armed forces currently have to prevent unwanted bodily waste issue? Or they just use common sense and remove their uniforms when nature calls? I'm sure there are people on here who have served and who may be able to comment on calls of nature while wearing bulky protective equipment.

Comment: Suggest you have a look at this Q&A on Quora: https://www.quora.com/What-do-soldiers-do-if-they-need-to-use-the-toilet-while-in-combat

I imagine Stormtroopers do what any soldier in the field does.

Comment: You move any inhibiting part of the uniform out of the way, whether that is taking it off or pushing it aside and do your business. You do it when it is possible i.e. not in the middle of a firefight. Basically you use common sense and do what any other normal 'person' would do

Comment: Apparently some of you who thought my question required laughter and deridement from some of you folks.  If a Stormtrooper is wearing a full fitting one piece bodyglove,how do you get if off and on quickly, if you're in the middle of a battle?  Plus, if anyone of you folks are military, think of being in MOPP#4, where you're wearing a full hooded protective mask, MOP suit, taped gloves and ankles, plus wearing  all of your armor, and extra gear, then you have to appreciate, how do you go, if you're in full stormtrooper armor?  Yes, you can change, but you're giong to smell to high heaven.

Comment: @CameronGarcia You're reference example explains the answer you go when you aren't in danger and you can take the clothes off to do so. Also as shown in The Force Awakens the storm trooper armour isn't a 'onesie' but made up of separate pieces.

Comment: Even if we take into account that they have complicated to get out of armour........one rl example who needed to use the restroom AND had even more complicated to get out of armour exists.......the european knights....they had plate mail sometimes needed to be lifted onto their horses and surely couldn't have gotten out of their armour in time easily. So somehow it still works with complicated armour and restroom.

Answer (score 7):

Your question is made up of two main questions:

*1. How did Stormtroopers prevent having to eliminate urine and fecal waste, at the wrong time?*

*2. Did they have a enhanced digestive and urinary system that allowed a very small amount of urine and feces to be expelled at a longer time than humans?*

**2 is probably easier to answer first:**

The Wookieepedia page on [Clone Troopers](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Clone_trooper/Legends) lists some physical enhancements that were made, in addtion to the behavioural:

> ...the Kaminoans tampered with Fett's DNA to ensure that the clones were primarily dominated by behavioral genes that emphasized certain qualities such as loyalty, aggression, independence and discipline in order to guarantee that the army would be more docile and less independent than their template. **Additionally, the Kaminoans increased their clones' lung capacity, decreased their reaction times and improved their stamina. Certain allergies and Fett's mild astigmatism were also removed from the genome.**

Since there is no mention of an altered digestion system, and the fact the the progentior is  a human who has been seen eating, I think we could assume that basic bodily functions still exist as we know it.

**1. So, how do the avoid untimley bowel movements?**

This [answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7567/what-is-life-like-for-a-clone-or-storm-trooper) suggests that Stormtroopers are slaves who are moved around alot. **My speculation is that they would either 'hold it in' or 'just go when they can'.** These are highly trained, physically enhanced soldiers, who have been drilled since birth to obey and serve. I imagine that they would probably see the need as expel waste as a very short task that can be completed at the most appropriate time during their mission.

**Tl;dr** - They're mostly normal humans, who go to the bathroom when it makes strategic sense to do so.