# Why don't people have allergies on certain planets in Star Wars?

Tags: star-wars, science, genetic-engineering

I recently finished *The High Republic: Defy the Storm* (Canon High Republic Phase III YA novel) and on pg. 300, something very intriguing is said:

> Cair immediately began charming everyone with smiles and questions about their meal customs and if anyone was allergic to anything, and how that was something that had surprised him about the frontier-allergies. "It wasn't a problem on Naboo" he said

This got my brain whirling and I started thinking about sci-fi reasons for why this is. Naboo, is a highly advanced planet with a great standard of living, so my  guess was that the citizens of Naboo have used genetic engineering to eliminate allergens in food OR genetically engineer people from birth to not have food allergies at all. I am leaning more towards the former as, in *Star Wars*, genetic engineering of sentient beings has been declared illegal (according to *The Mandalorian* Season 3) BUT Naboo is very advanced, so it's possible these laws work on a planet-to-planet basis?

Comment: FWIW, we know that there exist people who are allergic to bacta, c.f. [Ton Phanan](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ton_Phanan)

Comment: Oh, and [allergies were eliminated from the Fett genome](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/150360/stormtrooper-sanitation).

Comment: And why don't [Vulptices](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Vulptex) have persistent [arterial hypertension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertension)?!?

Comment: More to the point, why don't people just die in alien environments .. "that plant you just sniffed produces coof spike protein in its pollen, you know that?"

Comment: I think the allergies question has more merit than some obscure, exotic species of animal

Comment: The number of people with allergies varies between different societies at present on Earth. The reasons are far from fully understood. One factor increasing dust mite allergies in the UK may be that most houses now have central.heating a keep windows closed to save money. Therefore people are exposed to more housemites than they were in the past.

Comment: Heck 20 or so years ago, people all suddenly developed allergies to peanuts so now nobody can have them on an airplane... :shrug:

Comment: @JudithJones Most of the research I have seen suggests that cleanliness is strongly related to allergies So people from sterile environments like corousant should have lots of allergies.. but people from bacteria laden environments should have very few... It holds out in real life as farm kids have 1/5th the number of allergies as city kids..

Comment: True.  Also there is some evidence that people with intestinal worms have far fewer of at least certain types of allergies.